# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'; while using room library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I am trying to make a simple book record app file using `Room` library for data storage. After finishing first two fragments I decided to test them. `Building` the code gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Here are my room implementations:

*Entity*

```
package com.example.books.data

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "book name")
    val bookName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author name")
    val bookAuthor: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "topic")
    val bookTopic: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    val bookStatus: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "chapter")
    val chapter: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "read percent")
    val readPercent: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pages read")
    val pagesRead: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total page")
    val totalPage: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    val dateCreated: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last read")
    val lastRead: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    val notes: String?
)
```

*Dao*

```
package com.example.books.data

import androidx.room.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface BookDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY `last read` DESC")
    fun getBooks(): Flow<List<Book>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = :id")
    fun getBook(id: Int) : Flow<Book>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(book: Book)
    @Update
    suspend fun update(book: Book)
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(book: Book)
}
```

*Database*

```
package com.example.books.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Book::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class BookDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun bookDao(): BookDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: BookDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : BookDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    BookDatabase::class.java,
                    "book_database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Application*

```
import android.app.Application
import com.example.books.data.BookDatabase

class BookListApplication : Application() {
    val database : BookDatabase by lazy { BookDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
}
```

*Gradle dependencies*

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
}
```

I tried to run the gradle console with
`.\gradlew clean build --debug --stacktrace`.
After running for a while, the command line gives me a warning saying Debug process may lick some sensitive information leaving the command incomplete.

As I loop back to where I begun, I decide to take it forward to the `StackOverflow` community. I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of frustration and double-checking, I figured a way out; although the solution is not quite acceptable to me.

Initially, I thought there must be some minor mistakes/typos implementing the `room` properties that I somehow missed, but that was not the case.

All I did was downgrade the `kotlin_versoin`. In my `buildscript.ext` of `project build.gradle` I changed to this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    }
    ...
}
```

From

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    }
    ...
}
```

To avoid `Kotlin jar files in classpath should have same version` warning I used the same `kotlin_version` in `kotlin-reflect` to make it compatible with `kotlin-stdlib`. In my gradle dependencies, I added

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"  //added
...
```

I don't know why it didn't work with the newest version. Besides, I don't really wanna downgrade.

Anyone here knows why? Knowing the answer would be satisfactory to me. Thanks!